# Word field.update loops in certain doc

Tags: c#, ms-word

Im using this code to update all the fields in a word document:

```
   private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Word.Field field in Doc.Fields)
        {
            try
            {
                field.Update();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

This works in most of my documents, but there is 1 document where somehow this code ends up in some loop. Only the ReportProgress throws an out of range error as its updating more fields then there should be in the document. but beside that im not seeing any error messages.

So now im looking on how to tackle this issue, maybe in code, or maybe find out what is wrong in the word document, but so far i have not found anything that helps me track the issue.

Is this maybe a known issue in word certain word documents?
Any other advice on how to tackle this or find what is wrong in the word doc ?

Comment: 1: Why do you loop the fields? Why not simply: doc.Fields.Update(); 2: It's usually not a good idea to work with Office in background threads. Office is STA...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your actual document I can only make a guess, but it might be that updating a particular fields modifies the fields collection you are iterating over.

A possible workaround in such a case would be to take a "snapshot" of the fields before you start looping:

```
var fieldsToUpdate = Doc.Fields.OfType<Field>().ToList();
foreach (var field in fieldsToUpdate)
{
    field.Update();
}
```

That way you can be certain that your foreach loop terminates.